# How/where to query phone spec from phone OS and build details

Tags: hardware, tech-specs

I have data that looks like this:

```
Linux; U; Android 5.0.1; SAMSUNG-SM-N910A Build/LRX22C
Linux; U; Android 4.3; SAMSUNG-SM-G900A Build/JSS15J
Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G900P Build/LRX22C
```

and I would like to attach characteristics to these devices, to do an equity study of student data. I can kind of know how old the phone is based on the OS used, but I would like to know more (how do I judge that a phone is "good" to help a student study). Is there an open data base that can be queried automatically? What other knowledge can I get from these data?

Comment: No definitions are as subjective as "good" and "bad". What's a "good" phone, in your opinion? By the way, the data above seems like a slice of three User-Agents, which are info that can be spoofed pretty easily. Plus, guessing the estimate age of a device by its OS version is pretty flawed as well; there are plenty of mods today, especially for Samsung devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully endorse comments of [Death Mask Salesman](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160863/how-where-to-query-phone-spec-from-phone-os-and-build-details#comment205953_160863)

> Is there an open data base that can be queried automatically?

One reliable database I am aware of is from Google itself

PDF at this link may help you [List of all devices supported by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en-GB)

There is also `.csv` available

Devices are listed in the following format - Marketing Name (Build.os.DEVICE/Build.os.MODEL)

To get device specs , there are many sites - [PDAdb](http://pdadb.net) is pretty good